# GetUserAvailability from Exchange from a COM Outlook addin

Tags: outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, outlook-object-model

I have a COM Outlook addin programmed in C++ (VS2005). I'm trying to see if within this addin I can get a random user or resource and see if it is available during  a certain meeting time. Basically I'm trying to do something like getuseravailability() from the 2007 Exchange Web Service api listed below.

[getuseravailability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.exchangeservicebinding.getuseravailability%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

Is this the only way to get this information? I've been looking through CDO, ADSI, MAPI and the Outlook object model but can't find anything else like it.  I'm avoiding using web services because the Exchange Servers I run against may not have it enabled/ may not be Exchange 2007. And also, I'm hoping for a COM api easily integrated with the existing Outlook COM addin, was really hoping for an OOM solution.

Am I wrong or would the webservices sdk require .net to be installed on the machine running the addin as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found a way to do this with CDO.  Will be trying a sample app for this to see if it does what I think it does.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms870482%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx

I didn't find this earlier because the MSDN library's default view doesn't easily let you browse through the table of contents for a section. You have to go into MSDNs preferences and choose "Classic View" to get the table of contents view on the left.